# If I get a credit card that will give me a higher credit limit if I make on-time payments, will it carry over if there is no balance?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit

So, I got a card, and let's say I was approved for $300, but the creditor promised to increase it to an actual credit line if I made five on-time payments starting in April.

So, I make a few payments, but by the third payment, I pay it off in full, and then I get a statement saying that no payment is due because there is no outstanding balance, so therefore, there will be no fourth payment. Will that fourth payment roll over to the next month, or will it simply be ignored and move on to the fifth payment?

Comment: "_but the creditor promised to_" It would depend on the nature of that promise, .i.e. the exact wording of the specific card-issuer's terms and conditions. _Common sense_ would _suggest_ that the wording would be more concerned with _avoiding late payments_, and so should only apply if there _is_ something to pay. However, "_common sense_" and "_terms and conditions_" sometimes don't share the same bed, so anything's possible.

Comment: It's impossible to say without reading the wording of the offer you were made.

Comment: I don't know if it would help to add the name of the credit issuer...

Comment: it would not. You have to post the fineprint (or read it yourself).